# Error while creating KVM network interface

Tags: 14.04, networking, kvm-virtualization, network-bridge

I am trying to configure a new network interface in the Virtual Machine Manager for the KVM platform.

Creating the network interface fails with following error:

[image: Here is the snapshot of error]

I am copying the error also here:

```
**Error creating interface:     
'Could not create interface: internal error: failed to create (start) interface eth0.1: unspecified error - interface eth0.1 failed to become active - possible disconnected cable.'**
```

(The creation of any network interface ends with the same error.)

Can someone point out the problem please?